# SQL how to express "not equal to and not less than"

Tags: sql

I am trying to use a comparison operator in SQL to say where **not** equal to or less than zero.

I have tried this but it comes up with an error

```
WHERE amount (<> 0 or < 0)
```

I have also tried:

```
WHERE amount !<= 0
```

but get syntax errors. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `where amount >= 1`

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to just being != 0, and I can prove it

Comment: I meant what op tried here "WHERE amount (<> 0 or < 0)", but now that I saw the title of the question I understand that there might be some confusion

Comment: This question requires more details/clarity to be answered. I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
 WHERE amount > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With propositional logic, your condition is the same as a != 0:

a != 0 or a < 0

(a < 0 or a > 0) or a < 0

(a < 0) or (a > 0) or (a < 0)

two repeated conditions with or, you can just remove one

(a < 0) or (a > 0)

equivalent to a != 0

aka a <> 0

Comment: The statement was "not equal to and not less than", which evaluates to ((a <> 0) and (not (a < 0))). If a is -1, then a <> 0 is true, but (not (a < 0)) is false, while your a <> 0 would yield true in that case. Hence, your formula is incorrect in its attempt to represent the statement the asker asked about.

Comment: question is messed up, I tried to show that the condition he used in the body is the same as <>

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding here. The **not** equal to or less than zero in the question actually means not (equal to or less than zero). We can know this from the fact that the **not** is bolded and separated from the rest of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

"not equal to and not less than" <=> "not (equal to or less than)" (see the De Morgan formulas here https://www.cuemath.com/data/de-morgans-law/), I have attached the screenshot of the relevant formula:

[image]

`foo` equal 0 to is represented as

```
foo = 0
```

`foo` less than 0 is represented as

```
foo < 0
```

`foo` equal to 0 or `foo` is less than 0 is represented as

```
foo = 0 OR foo < 0
```

this can be shortened to

```
foo <= 0
```

its negation is

```
NOT (foo <= 0)
```

alternatively, you can use

```
foo > 0
```

Note that `NULL` is a special case and you need to define what you intend `NULL` to yield. Since that was not specified, I'm focusing only on numeric inputs, but, at the end of the line, you will need to take into account `NULL` as a possible value as well if... Well, if it's possible in your scenario.